# Passing values between components: Pass References vs Subjects

Tags: javascript, angular

tl;dr: Why not pass variables by reference between components to have them work on the same data instead of using e.g. BehaviorSubjects?

I'm writing a sort of diary application in Angular 8. I have two components (Navbar and Dashboard) and a service (EntryService).

Navbar lists the entries, Dashboard provides the textarea, EntryService glues them together and communicates with the database.

While debugging the application I stumbled upon a way to communicate between the service and a component that i haven't thought of before.

By accident I passed a variable (entry: Entry) from the Dashboard *by reference* to the EntryService. The service saved to the database getting a unique ID back and saving this ID into the entry variable. This change immediately reflected to the Dashboard because of the 'passing by reference'.

Until now I was using Subjects to update the components on changes, but passing references around seems to be much simpler, because I want to work on the same data on both components and the service.

I've studied Angular for a while now and not read about this approach, so I'm wondering if it is a bad idea or design and if yes why?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: It depends on what you are doing, use an observable only when the value can change at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Passing by reference can be handy. But as a general approach to keep the application components in sync it has some draw backs. With Subjects you can easily investigate in which places of the application the value of the Subject will be changed by checking where the Subject.next() function is being called. When you pass your object by reference to a hundred components/services it will be much more difficult to find out, which of them modify the object and more importantly when, becaue often you want to trigger other changes afterwards. When you subscribe to Subjects, you get notifications about changes and can react to them. Subjects and Subscribers are an example for an Observer/Observable pattern, it allows you to decouple your application logic. And they are much more flexible, for example you can have a Subject which can return the last x number of changes or you can debounce the changes when you track user input, you can apply filters to them etc.